# Cannot change the owner, group of a softlink to a file

Tags: linux, symlink, rhel

Hi I am using the below to check for the files which are owned by user not defined in system configuration:

```
df --local -P | awk {'if (NR!=1) print $6'} | xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -nouser -ls
```

The result is:

```
3282546    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 613      users          19 Feb 12 12:46 /apps/omni/streams/lib32/libstreams.c -> ../lib/libstreams.c
```

The actual file has owner,group as:

```
# ll /apps/omni/streams/lib/libstreams.c
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 7668 Jan 17  2014 /apps/omni/streams/lib/libstreams.c
```

I want to change the owner,group of the link as well to root. I'm using the below, but it doesn't work:

```
 df --local -P | awk {'if (NR!=1) print $6'} | xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -nouser | xargs chown root:root
```

Anything I'm missing ?

Comment: run this: `df --local -P | awk {'if (NR!=1) print $6'} | xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -nouser | xargs -I filename echo chown root:root filename`, this will show what you're trying to do  per file. Please add the output.

Comment: My version of `chown` says that the option `-h` will not dereference the symlink - so `chown -h root:root somelink`... Oh the other hand, I've seen some instances where all symlinks are owned by `root`, regardless of who created them - but that's obviously not your case here...

Comment: @twalberg : sweet, `-h` works..thanks !